# Django 1.6.2 - Python 3.3 - MySQL 5.6.17 Connector issue on Windows 7/8

Tags: python, mysql, django, windows

I tried doing:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

But this error showed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 14, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

I did download Python 3.3.5 from here: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-335/

And the MySQL - Python connector from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

I'm trying to set this up on a Windows machine. Trying this is no luck as well:

```
pip install mysql-python
```

Comment: Django does not use MySQL Connector. Noboday use it.

Comment: What do you mean @Leonardo.Z?

Answer (score 0):

change engine in settings.py as
'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',